# Passing parameter with a4j:mediaOutput

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

im trying to pass some parameters from my a4j:mediaOutput to my bean. I can pass the OutputStream parameter and the second parameter (a reference to the value attribute of the component).

But i need to pass two other parameters too: the height and width of the mediaOutput. 
I tried it with *f:param* and *a4j:actionparam*, but both didnt worked.

```
<a4j:mediaOutput
       style="width: 200px; height:100px; max-width: 200px;max-height: 200px" 
           element="img" mimeType="image/jpeg" 
           createContent="# {bean.paint}"
           value="#{row}" cacheable="false" id="mediaOut">
    <a4j:param name="w" value="screen.height"
         assignTo="#{bean.screenHeight}"
         noEscape="true" />
</a4j:mediaOutput>
```

Any idea how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it works with f:param. I just didnt read it right in my bean with the FacesContext.

f.e for the width:

```
FacesContext fContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
width = Integer.valueOf((String) fContext.getExternalContext()
       .getRequestParameterMap().get("w"));
```